# Cannot load files with http request from integrated local webserver of Ionic app when in background in iOS 10

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, wkwebview

*tl;dr:*

In an iOS 10 App, built with the Ionic framework as a hybrid app in a WKWebView Container, how can I access data from the local webserver when the App is in the background and iOS 10 is aggressively terminating that communication? JS code execution works fine, it's just the data download that's not working.
I don't have this problem with Android. Can anybody help or provide better solutions/hints?

*Verbose version:*

I am looking for a hint how to workaround this problem, because I don't really believe in a solution after trying for days:

**Existing environment / Background**

My Ionic 1 app uses a local webserver (GCDWebserver) to serve files in my www directory to the app. I use the Cordova WKWebview Engine as container for the app (instead of the deprecated UIWebView). The app runs on iOS 9+ and Android 5+, for Android I still use Crosswalk (it gave me better performance in scrollable lists with large images). The app makes intensive use of the Geolocation features, mainly creating Geofences around points of interest, with the coordinates, details etc. loaded locally from JSON files. When such a Geofence is reached, the corresponding POI of the tour is loaded (with details as text, images) and an Audio file is played. Upon reaching the next geofence, the next POI is loaded and so on. This should happen without user interaction, like it was on autoplay.

The JSON files, that hold the information to the next POIs, are loaded via Angular's $http.get function due to the reason I have to use a local webserver to load the files and maybe later load them from another server.

**What works**

When the app is in foreground, I have absolutely no problems tracking the GPS location, reaching the Geofences, loading POIs and playing the sound.
Also when the app is in background, on Android and iOS aswell, the Location is tracked and reaches the Geofences and registers the POI as the next on the tour.

Summarized, background tracking, playing the Audio files and executing Javascript works in background mode. This is mainly achieved by using the [cordova-background-mode plugin and disablingWebViewOptimizations done by Android/Crosswalk](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#quirks) for Android and by using the above plugin in conjunction with [another more complex gps background plugin](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/) on iOS to keep the GPS tracking running precise in the background (without using Significant Region Monitoring since its to slow for this use case) and prevent the app from being suspended when not in foreground.

**The problem**

However, only on Android, the ressources (JSON that contains details and the path to the audio file and images) get loaded from the background, therefore proceeding the tour by playing the next audio file, loading images etc. while on iOS (10) this simply fails. I get an "Failed to load resource: http://localhost:54321/www/path/to/my/file.json" Error when debugging with Safari's developer console, but there is no filename, linenumber info or function stack to indicate where the error is thrown.

**My investigations**

The problem seems to occur from the fact, that iOS 10 has become very aggressive in restricting what Apps can do in the background, even though I have allowed the following Background Modes:

[image]

I have read that the included GCDWebserver in the cordova-labs-wkwebview-engine-localhost has it's JS process detached from the WebView Container (I'll include the link once I find it again), but my JS Code works fine in background, I also don't seem to have the problem of this gentleman: [Using WkWebWkit disables javascript execution/callback when app enters background](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence/issues/127)

Another theory was, that CORS was preventing my app from requesting the resources it needed, but then I should have had that problem in the foreground aswell, right?

In my config.xml i have these lines:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="cdvfile://*" />
```

and in my index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: file:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src 'self' * data:">
```

As already stated, this config works pretty well.

I can only test on a device on iOS 10, since the last iOS 9 device is long gone, but I think that problem would occur in iOS 9 also (since it also uses WKWebview) and I have to solve it for the next iOS Versions anyway.

**Workarounds tried so far / in progress**

Right now I use as a kind of indicator a notification sound when the next Geofence is reached, this works well since its only playing a standard system sound.

I have tried to circumvent the problem by using local notifications to signal to the user to tap them and open the app in foreground, but quickly got stuck because they can only be scheduled in foreground, when I don't need them and not be fired immediately in the background, when I needed them. [(There are some open issues about this here)](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1108) There may be a solution with another plugin, if I find one, I have to investigate this further.

In the meantime, I try to load the JSON with cordovaFile loader instead of a http.get request but I am very thankful for any hints you can give me, I don't have many more ideas left..

I can provide more config / sample code, however since this is a nearly production app for a customer I can't share all of the code or link to a hosted version of the app, it doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance

Ionic info:

`Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002`

cordova plugins ls:

`cocoon-cordova-labs-local-webserver 2.4.1 "CordovaLocalWebServer (Cocoon Mod)"
cocoon-cordova-labs-wkwebview-engine-localhost 0.5.1 "Cordova WKWebView Engine with http server (localhost) support (Cocoon Mod)"
cocoon-cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.1.1 "Cordova WKWebView Engine (Cocoon Mod)"
cordova-background-geolocation-lt 2.7.4 "BackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-background-fetch 4.0.4 "CDVBackgroundFetch"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-cocoalumberjack 0.0.4 "CocoaLumberjack"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation 0.0.1 "cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media 3.0.2-dev "Media"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.2.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"`